# How to customize built-in AspNet identity without using migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity-2

I created new web project in Visual Studio 2015 (community edition) and selected Individual Identity. I have followed instructions on using EF migration to sync up the code and database on customized user properties and it worked well.

However, if I don't want to use database migration, how can I add customized user properties? I manually added C# properties in ApplicationUser and DB table fields but always get "The model backing xxxxxContext has changed since the database was created ..." error. Should I add those table mappings in OnModelCreating() override?

Also for those who are happy with EF migration, how will this work in deployment to different environments?

Comment: Well, if you are going to be changing your model you need a way to get those into the other environments. During early development you can just use an initializer like DropCreateDatabase to get your changes into the DB. Once you have data you care about you need migrations. You can generate a SQL script that will update the schema in other environments.

Comment: I just figured out (thanks for other SO posts) that deleting/renaming __MigrationHistory table and call Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null) will disable this migration feature. Migration works for small/POC projects but for real applications a separate database project is much better in tracking changes and deployment management.

Comment: Well, we have been using migrations for a large scale "real" application for over 2 years now with 4 different environments (DEV, QA, TRAIN, PROD).  It works fine once you understand the issues.

Comment: The issue is that there is no change tracking on database schema - tables, indexes, why & who. The only thing you have is that _MigrationHistory table. For complicated LOB applications this is not desirable.

Comment: We get what we need from migrations combined with source control, but agree it's not for every situation.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is delete the `__MigrationHistory` table from your database - it's created by the Identity system when you register your first user.

It makes sense to not use code-first, when you have a dedicated database team or DB admin - in which case the application dev's don't do the database work.